# Firebase Database and Unity, saving, updating and loading a list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm very new to firebase and wanted to know what the best way to update and save a list is. Im saving my categories like this:

```
public void saveData()
{
    database.Child("Users").Child("Group 1").Child("Category").SetValueAsync(categoriesList);
}
```

But how can I detect when the list is changing and update my local categoriesList? (That would be more efficient than loading the whole list?)

And how can I load all Strings contained in categoriesList on Firebase and put them into the local categoriesList?

Comment: If you need any more Infos just tell me what you need.

Comment: You could subscribe to child changed events.  I have never done this, but checkout https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/child-changed-event-args.

Comment: Ok I will try that but I dont really know how to inplement that with code.